# React Native Firebase dynamic link iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I am trying to use RNFirebase to sign in into the app with email link

```
signInWithDynamicLink = async url => {
const { dispatch, navigation } = this.props;
const isWithEmail = RNFirebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(url);

if (isWithEmail) {
  try {
    dispatch(setSignInByEmail(true));
    const signInEmail = await AsyncStorage.getItem('emailForLogin');
    if (signInEmail) {
      await RNFirebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(signInEmail, url);
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem('emailForLogin');
    } else {
      // Handle non sign in email link
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I can retrieve the long email link with the apiKey in the `url` just fine in Android. however in iOS `url` is only the redirect url from the `actionCodeSettings`, so `isWithEmail` will always be `false`. Did I do something wrong within my code?

`url` in android `https://example.page.link/?link=https://project.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/...https://redirect-url.com%26lang%3Den`

in iOS `https://redirect-url.com`

Here is my AppDelegate.m for dynamic link handler

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {
  return [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
        restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {
  return [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

**Update**

never mind. only need to change the Associated Domain to the default dynamic link